# Drupal Module Permission

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I have followed the static permission for my module in drupal 8 and adding

```
csv_custom test_permission:
    title: 'CSV_Custom'
    description: 'CSV_Custom The description'
```

in my permissions.yml (tried to add restrict access: TRUE and False)

and also

```
csv_custom.admin_settings:

  path: '/admin/config/csv_custom'

  defaults:

    _form: '\Drupal\csv_custom\Form\jsonForm'

    _title: 'Json Form'

  requirements:

    _permission: 'csv_custom test_permission'
```

in my routing.yml

It does show up a page where i can edit permission, however when I logged in with the user role, it still shows restricted access. 
Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you have a role

> editor

and you want every user with this role is able to view the page

> /admin/config/csv_custom

then set permission for this role at this page

> /admin/people/permissions/editor

find your custom permission

> csv_custom test_permission

and set check box checked and save now every user who have this role "editor" has permission to view/go to the page

> /admin/config/csv_custom

Hope this make some sense for you
thanks